# Firebase - check if user created with Google Account is signing up or logging in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a web application, where you can log-in and register an account with a google account. I have managed to make it so they can log-in with the signInWithPopup(provider), but not sure how to Implement the sign-up. Any suggestions? or know of any functions in firebase i can use?

Comment: The answers given below no longer work for those using the most recent version of the firebase engine. The `additionalUserInfo` object no longer is returned in the `UserCredential` object.

Comment: @SpBills but works for modular sdk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There aren't any separate methods to `login` and `sign up` when using Google Sign-In or any other provider. If a user with that credential exists then user will be logged in else a new user account will be created. You can then use [`additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo) property from the result received from `signInWithPopUp` method to check if the user is new.

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
  const {additionalUserInfo: {isNewUser}} = result;

  console.log(isNewUser ? "This user just registered" : "Existing User")
})
```

For the new Modular SDK (`V9.0.0+`), the same can be written as:

```
import { signInWithPopup, getAdditionalUserInfo } from "firebase/auth"

const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);

// Pass the UserCredential   
const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you!! do you know if you can access the birthday of a google account with additionalUserInfo?

Comment: @gitmcgee you would have to add  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read` scope as well the the provider and then make a request to [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) using the accessToken. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515176/13130697) for detailed API usage.

Answer (score 1):

So far, as I understood, you have two options to log in to your website: one is to make a local username/password account on your website, and the other option is to use your google account. I suppose the best way would be to check if the Google account is linked to any existing user using `additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`, and then linking up your google account with the account that is created via your website locally by following this article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking?hl=lt

Answer (score 1):

Once you have Firebase dependency inside your application. You can use createUserWithEmailAndPassword method to do that.

```
firebase
.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("email@domain.com", "123123")
.then(data => {
    data.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.form.name
    }).then(() => {});
})
.catch(err => {
    this.error = err.message;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the way in which you are implementing user sign-in, you can use the following approach.

Get the user object from `useAuthState` (a method of [react-firebase-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks)) and check if its `creationTime` = `lastSignInTime`. Following is the implementation:

```
  const [user, isLoginLoading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const isNewUser = user.metadata.creationTime === user.metadata.lastSignInTime;
      if (isNewUser) {
        // User signed up
      } else {
        // User logged in (not first time)
      }
    }
  }, [user]);
```